# Why are 20% of keywords still provided when Google is using HTTPS across the board?

Tags: google-analytics, keywords, referrer, not-provided

Most of the searches that appear in my analytics are "not provided" because Google has encrypted their all searches.  However, if all search results are now encrypted with HTTPS protocol then how is Google analytics still able to track some (20%) of the organic keywords details?

There are still some keywords appearing in my organic keywords section. So how did Google analytics do this tracking?   Does it bypass the HTTPS restrictions for the referrer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is an easy one. It has nothing to do with the site using HTTPS, but rather the user using HTTPS to access Google. The keywords you are seeing are a result of doing a search on Google with HTTP.

Comment: It is very difficult to search Google without SSL these days.  The only way that I can manage it is to use private browsing and visit `http://www.google.com/` which redirects you to `https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl`  If you then change the https back to http you can remain without SSL.  I can't imagine that 20% of users are doing that.

Comment: I actually agree with you. But that is how it works. I assume (wildly) that not all Google sites require HTTPS. You can find plenty of info on this using: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=google+analytics+keyword+not+provided

Comment: Thanks for comment @closetnoc. But this not the case here, Google has encrypted all searches no matter whether you are log in, log-out, using incognito or even trying to access HTTP site by manually typing the address in URL bar.

Comment: I have not confirmed this, but I heard that some browsers can ignore the HTTP to HTTPS redirect. I heard that Firefox can do this, but that just may be blather. I heard that there were settings in some browsers that allowed this behavior. Why would someone want to do this? To cheat Google of valuable data and stay private. This is a rumor that I have not checked out. Also consider that not all of your traffic is coming from your locale. Plus there are search aggregators that may not be using HTTPS. There is leakage. I have not studied it enough to know all the ins and outs.